# Jointly determining the weighting matrix and target vector in weighted least square

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, finite-impulse-response, digital-filters, least-squares

I have the same weighted least square form [weighted least square](https://mattsdsp.blogspot.com/2022/10/fir-filters-with-prescribed-magnitude.html) composed of diagonal weighting matrix $ W $, IDFT matrix $F({\omega})$, desired response vector $D({\omega})$ and FIR Filter coefficients $h$,
$$
 min_{h} \sqrt{W} \{ F({\omega})h - D({\omega}) \}
$$

The closed form of the first problem is $(\sqrt{W}  F({\omega}))^{\dagger}\sqrt{W}D(\omega)$. It alleviated degradation in the edge band that the modification of the weighting matrix allocated higher weighting in edge bands. Therefore, I want to solve the problem relative to the weighting matrix $W$ simultaneously. My thought is solving the subproblem
$$
 min_{W} \sqrt{W} \{ F({\omega})h - D({\omega}) \}.
$$

The problem can be transformed into

$$
\{ F({\omega})h - D({\omega}) \}^{H} \sqrt{W}^{H}  = 0.
$$
We let the $B = \{ F({\omega})h - D({\omega}) \}^{H}$.
Referring to [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4578576/symmetric-vector-least-squares-solution), we can obtain the closed-form homogeneous solution of this problem by

$$
  \sqrt{W}^{H} = I - B^{\dagger}B
$$
The overall algorithm is to iteratively solve $h$ and $W$ by fixing one of them. I found that the edge band can't improve by solving this problem. My problem is **whether there exists a closed form constraint to jointly solve both of the $W$ and $h$ for improving the edge band performance**. Any paper, website, idea are welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. What is the "best" weight matrix for your application? Normally, you use $W$ to emphasize certain frequency regions and to achieve a smaller error there compared to other frequency intervals. If you minimize the approximation error by varying $W$ (which to my understanding doesn't make sense), then the best solution is $W=0$ (which is of course useless).

Comment: Hello @MattL. , I found that the changing weight of W
 certainly optimizes the edge band performance when the edge weighting is allocated more. I found the weighting matrix can't not make the overall algorithm perform well. I changed my problem. I want the edge band perform well. How can I plug some close-form constraint to it ?

Comment: It looks like you're looking for a Chebyshev (minimax) solution, which can be computed using the Parks-McClellan algorithms. For such designs, the maximum error is constant and doesn't increase close to the band edges.

Comment: Hello, @MattL., do you mean that the edge band constraint can be  transformed into unconstrained problem therefore the Lagrange multiplier induced the changing factor in the weighting matrix. The unconstrained problem can be solved by Iterative Reweighted Least Square depended on Chebyshev solution?

Comment: You could use an IRLS approach to compute a Chebyshev solution, but there are also other methods that are often more efficient, such as the Remez algorithm, which is used in the Parks-McClellan algorithm.

Comment: It's a nice direction to develop the algorithm, thx for your sugestion